# How to use ComPtr in C++Builder?

Tags: smart-pointers, directx-11, c++builder-11-alexandria

I'm trying to implement DX11 in my C++Builder project. All SDK references use the `ComPtr<>` template, eg:

```
// Create the DX11 API device object, and get a corresponding context.
ComPtr<ID3D11Device> device;
ComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> context;
```

Of course, C++Builder doesn't know `ComPtr`, so how can I include it, or port over the `ComPtr` template? Basically, get it to work in C++Builder.

**UPDATE**

So, someone asked me about the headers. Obviously, I don't have the needed header, hence I'm asking here for a solution.

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <d2d1.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
```

According to Microsoft, I should include `<client.h>`, but that one can't be found by C++Builder.

Comment: Show us your headers.

Comment: _"According to Microsoft I should include `<client.h>`"_ - Please tell us exactly where you got that, such as a documentation link.

Comment: try `#include <wrl\client.h>` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/wrl/how-to-activate-and-use-a-windows-runtime-component-using-wrl?view=msvc-170

Comment: `WRL is now superseded by C++/WinRT` so maybe just use `winrt::com_ptr` instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/wrl/windows-runtime-cpp-template-library-wrl?view=msvc-170

Comment: `ComPtr` ships with `WRL` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/wrl/windows-runtime-cpp-template-library-wrl) which today ships with the Windows SDK https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/ once installed, it will be in a path like this `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\winrt\wrl`. PS: you can also get it from mingw (like in msys64\mingw64\include) but I wouldn't recommend this one.

Answer (score 0):

`ATL::CComPtr` is a Microsoft class. I believe that it's in Microsoft's atlcom.h or atlcomcli.h. There will be an MFC equivalent.

If you don't have Visual Studio, the template will be like:

```
template<typename T>
class CComPtr
{
    T *m_pObj;
public:
    CComPtr() : m_pObj(nullptr) {}
    CComPtr(T *p) : m_pObj(p)
    {
        p->AddRef();
    }
    ~CComPtr();

    HRESULT CreateInstance(REFCLSID rclsid, DWORD dwClsContext, LPUNKNOWN pUnkOuter=nullptr, REFIID    riid = IID_IUnknown)
    {
        ASSERTE(m_pObj == nullptr); // if not, release first
        return CoCreateInstance(rclsid, pUnkOuter, dwClasContext, riid, &m_pObj);
    }

    void Release()
    {
        if (m_pObj)
            m_pObj->Release();
        m_pObj = nullptr;
    }

    // These methods access the pointer without adding or releasing references.
    void Attach(T *p);
    T* Detach();

    // non-modifying operator overloads
    T* operator *();
    T* operator ->();
    operator bool();
    // modifying overload - Pointer should be null before use.
    T** operator &();
};
```

Comment: The question is about `ComPtr`, not `CComPtr`. `ComPtr` is from WRL, not from ATL (which indeeds only comes with Visual Studio)

Answer (score 0):

C++Builder has its own smart-interface-pointer classes, such as `TComInterface` in `<utilcls.h>`:

```
#include <utilcls.h>

TComInterface<ID3D11Device> device;
TComInterface<ID3D11DeviceContext> context;
```